# System.Windows.Forms.Timer And MessageBox

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

can someone please let me know why the System.Windows.Forms.Timer continues to show multiple message boxes? I thought that it is on GUI thread ... and therefore after the first messagebox the GUI thread should block. But this is not the case

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    int nValue = 0;

    void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        nValue++;
        MessageBox.Show(nValue.ToString());
    }

    System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    private void btnStartTimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        tmr.Interval = 500;
        tmr.Enabled = true;
        tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `MessageBox.Show()` method includes (as all modal dialogs do) a message loop that continues to pump window messages.

Window messages are what allow a window to interact with the user (update itself, accept input, etc.), as well as what allows the `Forms.Timer` class to work.

If you want your `Forms.Timer` to stop ticking when the dialog is shown, you need to set the timer's `Enabled` property to `false` before you show the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

In your Tick event stop the timer and then start again after `MessageBox.Show` like:

```
void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tmr.Enabled = false;
    nValue++;
    MessageBox.Show(nValue.ToString());
    tmr.Enabled = true; 
}
```

The reason you are getting repeated MessgeBoxes is because your timer is continuing after showing the first MessageBox.

Answer (score 2):

A message box does not block the GUI-Thread. It's as simple as that. You can interact with the message box, after all :)

Also: The internal workings of the timer are not clear, but I would guess that it runs on another thread and just returns on the GUI-Thread.

Comment: Actually, the internal works of `System.Forms.Timer` are clear, if one looks at the code. :) And it uses the native Win32 `SetTimer()` function, with a null `TIMERPROC`, meaning that each tick of the timer is reported via a `WM_TIMER` message to the associated window.

Comment: Ah, nice to know, thank you. In the next Framework-Version or running on mono it could be implemented in other ways. It's a great learning exercise to look at framework code, but one should never assume the implementation as given (Blackbox, etc.).

Comment: It is an implementation detail, true. However, the particulars of the documented behavior make it highly unlikely it would be implemented any other way on Windows. If Windows didn't already have WM_TIMER support, I doubt there'd even have been a `Timer` class in the Forms namespace. On Mono, I have no idea...I don't even know what the equivalent to WM_TIMER is on *nix GUIs, or if one even exists. If there is one, then the above is probably (but not certainly) true for Mono as well...if not, then all bets are off.